# VSCode query format for searching for files, types, etc

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand what is the query format when I press (Cmd + P) or (Comd + T) and then type something.

Let's say I type `ABC`. it seems to me that VSCode searches using the regex `A.*B.*C.*`. Is it correct? It also appears that `*` is also allowed in the query, but I got confusing results, for example here

[image]

Can someone please point me out to the documentation about the query format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "fuzzy" matching or searching.  I couldn't find any formal documentation other than something like [implementing fuzzy matching.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/968) For your odd test case of vs*b it looks like they are trying to implement fuzzy matching with out-of-order symbols like some other editors have.

See also [More fuzzy matching:VSCode documenation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/968)

Comment: Note: new option: [PR 164376 "'`Fuzzy Match`' toggle"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/164376)

Answer (score 1):

The file picker is not using regular expressions, but a fuzzy search algorithm. I think this feature is somehow connected to IntelliSense, but I am not aware of any detailed technical documentation.
 However, it has been introduced in [December 2015 (VSCode 0.10.6)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vDecember#_file-picker-improvements-and-fuzzy-search) and became a default setting in [January 2016 (VSCode 0.10.9)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vJanuary#_file-picker).

On GitHub you can find an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27317) collecting bug reports / feature requests regarding the fuzzy searching. If you want to dig much deeper into this topic, you might find a good starting point there.

As a side note, also the `User Settings`(File > Preferences > Settings) seem to use the same kind of fuzzy search:
[image]